# ASP MVC SSL cross domain flash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, twitch

My site is utilizing SSL and it appears that while the user is in a secure connection they cannot accept outside media from unsecured sites. As the content will simply not load.

When the same page is loaded with the standard http://www.mypage.com all of the content loads correctly.

I am looking to embed a twitch stream into my page but I must continue to use SSL. I have seen the term CORS thrown around, does that apply to this issue?

Comment: You need to elaborate a little more, and what do you mean *may not work*... Find out if it works or not before you ask a question. Also, in general since IIS is where you configure SSL that is probably the first place to look.

Comment: I guess I should not have used words that implied doubt. It does not work and I know this for sure. It appears to be a common issue but I have not seen a solution for IIS. Most examples point to a cross domain.XML file which I am assuming is not part of IIS. I will look at the web.config file.